# How to trigger event only once until it is changed in composites?

Tags: android, kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to implement event google analytics. I would like to send an event only when the user enter to the screen and then when he changes the value of the string in the text  it should trigger one more. For now it triggers every time user sees the screen and even if he goes down and up my compose triggers again (even if the text is the same) and event sends data one more time when it shouldn't.
I was thinking about `LaunchedEffect`

What I've done so far is:

```
@Composable
private fun MyContent(
    sendAddEvent: (String) -> Unit
) {
    var lastMethod = "NoName"

        LaunchedEffect(lastMethod) {
           
            sendAddEvent(lastMethod)
        }

            TextChooser(
                onSelectedMethodChanged = {
                    lastMethod = it?.value ?: "NoName"
                },
            )
}
}
```

How should I make it proper? Should I make state? I do not think it is proper solution and it makes app goes down witout logs. Thanks in advance.

My try:

```
    var lastMethod by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    
    if (!lastMethod.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        LaunchedEffect(lastMethod) {
          
            sendAddEvent(lastMethod)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable you pass to LaunchedEffect is used to tell it to launch the effect again each time it changes. Since you don't want this to happen, you should use a value that never changes. Conventionally, this is done by passing `Unit` or `true`.

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    sendAddEvent(lastMethod)
}

// or

LaunchedEffect(true) {
    sendAddEvent(lastMethod)
}
```

I'm not sure what you're using your `lastMethod` variable for. You seem to be changing it, but it's not remembered and it is not State, so I don't see what changing it would accomplish.

Comment: I would like to launch this event if it changes, but not if it still the same value for example:
I write "test" on text and go down screen and up it is still "test", but with this it will goes only once so it is good.
When I write another text like "test5" it should trigger, but for now I have crash because of this. And also my question is should I use somekind of state variable? I;m quite new with composites. I come from view binding. thanks for any advice. launch effect here is it good?

Comment: Oh, that’s not what you said in your question. You said, “when changes value of the string it doesn’t matter.”  If you want it to change when the string changes, you need to remember this variable. Like I said in the question, there’s no point in having a non-remembered variable that you change the value of.

Comment: Sry it was late for me I meant it does not matter what you enter as a text. :)
 " I would like to send an event only when the user enter to the screen and then when he changes the value of the string in the text or something it does not matter... what you enter as a text."

What do you mean by remember this variable. How to achieve this in compose?

Comment: Look at my EDIT my comment "My try" it still when I scroll down and back it still triggers..;C: (

Comment: What happens if you move the `if` to inside the `LaunchedEffect` block? If that doesn't help, maybe there's something wrong with the setup of the outer composeable.